# OSGI Bundle with Android

Tags: android, osgi, dlna

I have been trying to get apache felix upnp stack working on androd using OSGI framework. I got a DMR up and running over a test OSGI framework ( knopplerfish ). However, I am unable to figure out how to make the DMR OSGI bundle working and can be activated on android.

What I need is not a source code or something else. I need a pro look to my issue. I mean what programming structure do I need to use to let bundle interact with android components ?

An interface between them ? if so what should be my way of use it ?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right thing to do here I really need help.

Comment: I think this question is too vague to solicit any useful responses. Can you post some error messages or sample code you've tried?